# Focus on inputfield after DOM is loaded with Blazor

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor

I want that my inputfield is focused when when I open the Website, it always focus the Link when I start it.
Secondly I have to Sacn muliple numbers into my inputfield with a Scanner. It triggers my function addToTable. So my number will be added to a list. after that It should clear the inputfield and focus on it again, so I can scan in the next number:

```
<input id="LeNumber" name="LeNumber"  @onkeydown="addToTable" @onclick:preventDefault="@isPreventDefault"/>

private async void addToTable(KeyboardEventArgs args)
{

 if (args.Key != "Tab")
 {
    LeNumber += args.Key.ToString();
 }
 else
 {
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(LeNumber))
    {
        if (todos.Contains(LeNumber))
        {
            LeNumber = null;
            await SetValueBack("LeNumber");
            await TurnRed("table");
            await Focus("LeNumber");

        }
        else
        {
            if (LeNumber == "submit")
            {
                generateXml();
                b += 1;
            }
            else
            {

                todos.Add(LeNumber);
                LeNumber = null;

                await SetValueBack("LeNumber");
                await TurnNormal("table");
                await Focus("LeNumber");
            }
        }
    }
 }
}
```

The Problem now is that it doesn't set the focus back on my inputfield. To set my Focus I have a JS Function witch do: document.getElementByID(id).focus().
That doesn't work but it works if I put a delay in like the following:

```
function focusElement(id) {
 setTimeout(function () {
    document.getElementById(id).focus();
 }, 3000);  
}
```

I Think it doesnt work because the focus gets lost when it displays the List:

```
                    @{
                    for (int i = 0; i < todos.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (i % 2 == 0)
                        {
                            @:<tr>
                                <td>@todos[i]</td>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <td>@todos[i]</td>
                            @:</tr>
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Is there a way to set the focus after everything is done? Because It would be very "ugly" to do this with the delay

Answer (score 0):

Blazor has a method for this.  `FocusAsync()`.

I believe if you call it in the `OnAfterRender` handler, or in your event handlers, you will achieve what you want.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lLypM7oBwyA

Comment: I've tried to apply it on my project. It focus the inputfield when i click on the home button to route for that page, but not when I open up the website. Also, the Focus is still not set on my inputfield, the focus is still stolen from the input field.

Comment: Did you put it in `OnAfterRender`?

Comment: Yes, I did. It focus the field also on refresh but not when I first start it